# deleting rows iteratively until condition is met

Tags: r

I couldn’t find a solution to my specific question so I’m posting here. I have data frame that changes based daily calculations. But essentially what I want to do is to delete the last rows if the value contains a zero and stop when all three variables (A, B, C) have a value. For example:

DF

```
A  B C
4  3 7
3  3 4
7  0 4
4  7 0
```

Intended output

DF

```
A  B  C
4  3  7
3  3  4
```

So in this case I want to delete the last two rows because B and C have zero’s in it. But this is not always the case. Sometimes it’s only the last row that needs deleting, sometimes it’s the last three rows. Essentially I’m looking for something like this:

```
df<-last(df[!(d$B=0 | df$C=0),])
```

I need the code to look at the last row and delete it until the criteria of not having any zero’s is met.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out row indices where all the values are non-zero in all the column and select all the rows till `max` value of it.

```
df[seq_len(max(which(rowSums(df == 0) == 0))),]
#This is same as
#df[1:max(which(rowSums(df == 0) == 0)),]

#  A B C
#1 4 3 7
#2 3 3 4
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(4L, 3L, 7L, 4L), B = c(3L, 3L, 0L, 7L), 
C = c(7L, 4L, 4L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution

```
df %>% 
  filter_all(all_vars(. != 0))

df %>% 
  filter(across(everything(), .fns = function(x) x != 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

The dplyr/tidyr option is maybe more intuitive. Replace zeros with NA, then drop all rows with at least one NA:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  na_if(0) %>% 
  drop_na()
```

```
  A B C
1 4 3 7
2 3 3 4
```

Comment: Thanks all! All viable answers